# Macro to select first non-empty cell in entire sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose there is only one non-empty cell in a sheet and you want a macro to find it. So far I have the following code but am struggling to adjust it so it  searches all columns, not only one:

```
Sub FirstNonEmpty()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each cell In ws.Columns(1).Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select: Exit For
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Perhaps there is a way to use a variable equal to all columns instead of "1" in "ws.Columns(1).Cells"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `For` statement to:

```
For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Cells
```

which has the benefit of not scanning the rows/columns at the end of the worksheet as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the top formulation if the non-blank cell does not contain a formula, or use xlcelltypeformulas if it's a formula. If you know there is a non-blank, you don't need the On Error. In fact if there is definitely only one you don't need the (1) either.

```
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeconstants)(1).Select
'or
'ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeformulas)(1).Select
```

Comment: Did you mean `xlCellTypeBlanks` ? OP asked about non-empty cell ? Maybe `xlCellTypeConstants` ?

Comment: Oops, thank you @RobinMackenzie. I have comprehension difficulties.

Comment: Good call @RobinMackenzie , I misunderstood the question also, thinking he was looking for the first empty cell. DUH. You're not the only one SJR

Answer (score 1):

Or you may give this a try...

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Cells.Find(what:="*", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Rng.Select
End If
```